# how to switch b/w the login window and main window by clicking the button in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, toplevel

How to switch b/w the login window and main window? I know this types of questions are asked a lot but still i am not satisfied with the answer and please use method only helps me a lot.

```
from tkinter import *
def main_window():
    win2=Tk()
    label=Label(win2,text="helow").pack()
    Button(win2,text="logout",command=login_window).pack()
    win2.mainloop()

def login_window():
    win1=Tk()
    Label(win1,text="Password").pack()
    button1=Button(win1,text="click",command=main_window).pack()
    Entry(win1).pack()
    win1.mainloop()

login_window()
```

Comment: Use a single Tk() call, and make a *Frame* for login and main window. Then you can `destroy()` and `pack()` the Frames to change the window.

Comment: You should never create more than one instance of `Tk`, and never call `mainloop()` more than once.

Comment: @Novel ok ,i will try to use frames

Comment: from tkinter import *

def main_window():
    #f2.pack_forget()
    f2.destroy()
    label=Label(f1,text="helow").pack()
    Button(f1,text="logout",command=login_window).pack()
    f1.pack()

def login_window():
    #f1.pack_forget()
    f1.destroy()
    Label(f2,text="Password").pack()
    button1=Button(f2,text="click",command=main_window).pack()
    Entry(f2).pack()
    f2.pack()
win =Tk()
f1=Frame(win)
f2=Frame(win)
login_window()
win.mainloop()
#it is generating  error:=-_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!frame"

Comment: from tkinter import *

def main_window():
    #f2.pack_forget()
    f2.destroy()
    label=Label(f1,text="helow").pack()
    Button(f1,text="logout",command=login_window).pack()
    f1.pack()

def login_window():
    #f1.pack_forget()
    f1.destroy()
    Label(f2,text="Password").pack()
    button1=Button(f2,text="click",command=main_window).pack()
    Entry(f2).pack()
    f2.pack()
win =Tk()
f1=Frame(win)
f2=Frame(win)
login_window()
win.mainloop()
#it is generating  error:=-_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!frame"

Comment: from tkinter import *

def main_window():
    #f2.pack_forget()
    f2.destroy()
    label=Label(f1,text="helow").pack()
    Button(f1,text="logout",command=login_window).pack()
    f1.pack()

def login_window():
    #f1.pack_forget()
    f1.destroy()
    Label(f2,text="Password").pack()
    button1=Button(f2,text="click",command=main_window).pack()
    Entry(f2).pack()
    f2.pack()
win =Tk()
f1=Frame(win)
f2=Frame(win)
login_window()
win.mainloop()
#it is generating  error:=-_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!frame"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to use functions, this is what you can do:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

def main_window(win1):
    win1.destroy()
    win2=Frame(root)
    win2.pack()
    label=Label(win2,text="helow").pack()
    Button(win2,text="logout",command=lambda:login_window(win2)).pack()

def login_window(win2):
    win2.destroy()
    win1=Frame(root)
    win1.pack()
    Label(win1,text="Password").pack()
    button1=Button(win1,text="click",command=lambda:main_window(win1)).pack()
    Entry(win1).pack()

def login_window1():
    win1=Frame(root)
    win1.pack()
    Label(win1,text="Password").pack()
    button1=Button(win1,text="click",command=lambda:main_window(win1)).pack()
    Entry(win1).pack()

login_window1()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ty so very much ...my kind of coding :P

Comment: Also, it is better if you use classes for this. 
Happy to help! :)